# ASP.NET MVC pass model to KnockoutJS external file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've read many resources both on stackoverflow and through Google searches, but nothing seems to pertain particularly to my issue.

**tl;dr** I want to pass my C# model from my view to an external JS file (Knockout) so I can use that data from the model to display on my view.

### More info:

I have a pretty standard ASP.NET MVC 5 project with (for example), 1 view, 1 controller, & a C# view model that is retrieved and the data is manipulated in my C# controller. My external JavaScript file contains Knockout code, specifically I want to put that C# model into an observableArray in that external JS file so I can keep my Knockout code out of my view (aside from maybe a few lines).

### Example:

**books.js**

```
var app = (function (app) {
    app.FilterBooks = function () {
        var self = this,
        books = ko.observableArray(myC#Model);

        var data = [];
        self.BooksList = ko.computed(function(){
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(books(), function (item) {
                data.push(item);
            });
        });
        return data;
    };
return app;
}(app || {}));
```

`myC#Model` is the C# model that I want to retrieve from the view (or controller).

**Index.html**

```
@model viewModel

<div data-bind="foreach: BooksList">
    some knockout code in the view
    <p data-bind="text: bookName"></p>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var e = new app.FilterBooks;
            ko.applyBindings(e);
        });
    </script>
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //gets the list of all the books
    var viewModel = this.bookManager.GetAllBooks();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

#### Idea:

One solution I thought of would be to create a global variable and then I'd be able to access it in any JS files referenced after that, but this solution seems less than ideal. An example of that on my view would be: `window.booksVM = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));`

I'm hoping there is a better, more scalable solution that involves getting the model on the view and being able to access that model in my external JS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize out your model and pass it to your view model.
Use `ko.mapping` to map it from your model dynamically within your view model.

Providing that your collection contains an array that is books it will become an observable array automatically.

**View model**

```
var app = (function (app) {
    app.FilterBooks = function (data) {
        var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    };
return app;
}(app || {}));
```

**Index js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        var e = new app.FilterBooks(data);
        ko.applyBindings(e);
    });
</script>
```

**Update**

Also as mentioned by @james14 make sure you include the mapping plugin.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

```
PM> Install-Package Knockout.Mapping
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Knockout.Mapping

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! Also important to mention (at least I didn't know this), but I needed to include Knockout's mapping plugin, available here (or NuGet) http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: @jamez14 Thanks I will add that to the answer too.